# my android mobile app is crashing when clicking on any class, the error is showing below

Tags: android, error-handling

this is the error thats showing and i have no idea what it is

```
  E/UncaughtException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                             at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3522)
                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                             at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:681)
                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                             at com.ankoun.alex.sample3.ministry.onCreate(ministry.java:19)
                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1483625788005, fatal=1}]
    V/FA: Using measurement service
    V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                          at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3522)
                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                          at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:681)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                          at com.ankoun.alex.sample3.ministry.onCreate(ministry.java:19)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    W/ActivityThread: ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    E/FirebaseCrash: Error sending crash report
                     bnr: Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API has not been used in project ankoun-154421 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com/overview?project=ankoun-154421 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
                         at bob.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1053)
                         at boh.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:5055)
                         at boh.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:54)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

my app is on play store and its working on 20% of the phones but crashing on all the others can this be the error responsible for the crashing please help

Comment: Add your ministry.java Activity's xml file. Seems like you use high-resolution image as background for example

Comment: search on google `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be because of large bitmap. Either compress bitmap or do in Manifest as below:

```
<application
   ...
   android:largeHeap="true"
   ...>

</application>
```

Hope will help you!

Comment: thanks this worked fine. the app stopped crashing as it did before but i had 4 image views that where found in 4 different activities and now they are empty do you know anything about it ?

Comment: Can't understood your issue exactly, in deep please!

Comment: i have an image view and four buttons on the main activity and the image view has the logo to my app on some phones its showing normally but on the other phones the four buttons are showing without the image when i launch the activity.any tips ?

Comment: Your xml please! You may vote my answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image you are decoding is too large. Could you post your code and how big is the asset?

Answer (score 0):

Images or icon that you are using in your app, maybe large size or resolution, please make them small and less size.